# What is the equivalent CSS in IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have some HTML and CSS, both of which work in IE8 and up. However, in IE7, this does not work. Rather than having the wrapper be centered, it sits on the left. This CSS is the minimal amount for the question, nevertheless some *requirements* I have are the following:

- An absolutely positioned wrapper
- A flexible width (as set here to 90%, with the max and min width as well)
- A top of 39px (to account for a banner)

Hypothetically, I could do an IE7 hack to the extent of:

```
*left: 50%;
*margin-left: -45%;
```

But, I'd prefer not to... Anyway, here's the markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        #banner-wrapper {
            position: absolute;

            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;

            height: 39px; 
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 752px;

            background-color: rgb(95,95,95);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        #wrapper-main {
            position: absolute;

            top: 39px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;

            width: 90%;
            max-width: 1200px;
            min-width: 750px;
            min-height: 620px;

            background-color: lightblue;

            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            z-index: 0;
        }

        #wrapper-left {
            position: absolute;

            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;

            width: 180px;

            background-color: green;
        }

        #wrapper-content-container {
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 181px;
            height: 100%;

            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;

            overflow-y: scroll;
            z-index: 0;
        }

        #wrapper-content {
            position: relative;

            min-height: 900px;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 0;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="banner-wrapper"></div>
    <div id="wrapper-main">

        <div id="wrapper-left">THIS STAYS HERE</div>

        <div id="wrapper-content-container">
            <div id="wrapper-content">
               <!-- Scrollable content goes here -->
               THIS SCROLLS
            </div> 
        </div> 

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to make this work? A relatively positioned wrapper critically affects the design when in full form, and likewise, so does a fixed width. I'm out of ideas, but maybe someone else knows of a viable solution.

**Note:** I added more HTML/CSS to clarify some of the overall design.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just a question, why are you still supporting this awful browser?

Comment: I ask myself that routinely. However, it because of the particular cliental that could potentially encounter the site. I would really prefer to make the site at least somewhat "coherent" when viewed through IE7. But yes...the is an awful browser.

Comment: An absolutely positioned wrapper? That seems rather unnecessary if you only have a banner above it.

Comment: FYI, `display: block` on a `div` is almost definitely redundant and unnessecary.

Comment: You're correct. That was me throwing it in there because I was getting fed up with IE7 and figured why not... It has been removed accordingly.

Comment: It *does* seem likely that you can achieve whatever effect you're going for *without* the absolutely positioned wrapper.

Comment: As for the absolutely positioned wrapper: I did this because part of the design requires an overflow-y: scroll, which was not working with a relatively positioned wrapper. The scrollable content was getting hidden regardless - the only way to make it work was to have the position absolute. Maybe I missed something though.

Comment: Here's a JSfiddle with the asker's stuff plugged in as-is: http://jsfiddle.net/vSCgz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you mention not wanting to use an IE7 hack, here is a valid way of creating IE7 only styles without adding additional style sheets, this will solve your problem, add the following code

```
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7)]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
```

in place of your usual html tag.

You can then use:

```
.ie7 .css-selector {
```

to target any element in ie7 only.

For full disclosure, this works for all versions of ie if you use conditional comments such as:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
```